# Unable to enable yaru dark theme in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, themes, 20.04

I have installed `ubuntu-minimal` without recommends. I am trying to enable the Yaru Dark theme; even though it appears under the Appearance setting, nothing happens when I select `Dark`. (I have tried logging out and logging in, rebooting, etc.)

[image: Screenshot of Settings - Appearance]

The following packages are also installed:

```
$ apt-cache search yaru
yaru-theme-gnome-shell - Yaru GNOME Shell desktop theme from the Ubuntu Community
yaru-theme-gtk - Yaru GTK theme from the Ubuntu Community
yaru-theme-icon - Yaru icon theme from the Ubuntu Community
yaru-theme-sound - Yaru sound theme from the Ubuntu Community
pop-sound-theme - Pop sound theme
yaru-theme-unity - Yaru Unity theme from the Ubuntu Community
```

Am I missing a package? What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. I got the solution here(#5): 
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1798984

Comment: @RakeshGupta also worked for me, thank you! Strange that it is assumed as fixed

Comment: Thank you @RakeshGupta  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1798984/comments/5 fixed it for me